# Broadcast message are discarded by 40G NIC

Tags: networking, broadcast, high-availability, dpdk

I'm having a problem with the following 40G NIC adaptor when using DPDK 18:

> 04:00.3 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller
> X710 for 10GbE SFP+ (rev 02)

The DPDK uses driver *net_i40e*.

Apparently NIC drops broadcast packet with source MAC it owns.

Here is a more detailed description of what is going on.
I have a High-Availability environment with two routers.
Both routers registered  by means of *rte_eth_dev_mac_addr_add*() Virtual
MAC (00:00:5e:00:01:64) in addition to a physical burned-in MAC.
When the primary router sending broadcast VRRP-advertise message with
source MAC set to Virtual MAC, the secondary route's adapter seems to drop
the packet.

This is how the message looks like:

```
> Ethernet II, Src: 00:00:5e:00:01:64, Dst: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>     Destination: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>         Address: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>         .... ..1. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Locally administered
> address (this is NOT the factory default)
>         .... ...1 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Group address
> (multicast/broadcast)
>     Source: 00:00:5e:00:01:64
>         Address: 00:00:5e:00:01:64
>         .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address
> (factory default)
>         .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address
> (unicast)
>     Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
> Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.93.0.1, Dst: 255.255.255.255
>     0100 .... = Version: 4
>     .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
>     Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
>         0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0)
>         .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not ECN-Capable
> Transport (0)
>     Total Length: 32
>     Identification: 0x0000 (0)
>     Flags: 0x0000
>         0... .... .... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
>         .0.. .... .... .... = Don't fragment: Not set
>         ..0. .... .... .... = More fragments: Not set
>     ...0 0000 0000 0000 = Fragment offset: 0
>     Time to live: 255
>     Protocol: VRRP (112)
>     Header checksum: 0x0000 incorrect, should be 0xb110(may be caused by
> "IP checksum offload"?)
>     Source: 10.93.0.1
>     Destination: 255.255.255.255
> Virtual Router Redundancy Protocol
>     Version 3, Packet type 1 (Advertisement)
>         0011 .... = VRRP protocol version: 3
>         .... 0001 = VRRP packet type: Advertisement (1)
>     Virtual Rtr ID: 100
>     Priority: 254 (Non-default backup priority)
>     Addr Count: 1
>     0000 .... = Reserved: 0
>     .... 0000 0000 0001 = Adver Int: 1
>     Checksum: 0xf896 [correct]
>     [Checksum Status: Good]
>     IP Address: 0.31.205.8
>
```

Same code, same DPDK version but with 1G NICs works perfectly.

What I'm missing?

Thanks
Dima

Comment: The NIC you are having is X710, but port is 10G (please correct). If you want to receive packets with different MAC address please ensure you are enabling `rte_eth_dev_promiscous`. Please update with sample code or DPDK example you are using for reference to help you.

Comment: @VipinVarghese thanks for your response. Yes, the NIC is 40G, but autoconfigured to 10G speed. I don't want to work in promiscuous mode, so I register an additional MAC. It works for 1G cars we are using. I can not post the code, it's too clattered for SO :)

Comment: thanks for the response, API `rte_eth_dev_mac_addr_add` is to add list of DST mac address as whitelisted. In your explanation you are adding `00:00:5e:00:01:64`. but the packet you are receiving is with `Dst: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff` so I am not clear what is packet receive on the DPDK interface

Comment: @VipinVarghese The packet is broadcast (DST MAC ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:FF). Since it's broadcast I expect NIC to accept it. The message in the example is part of the VRRP protocol, to elect a master router in High-Availability (HA) environment.

The 00:00:5e:00:01:64 is virtual MAC (also part of VRRP protocol).
At any specific time, only the router, which is in HA mode master, owns it. The other router, in HA backup mode, won't send packets with the MAC and will drop any ingress packets with the MAC.

Comment: I think we should only look at i40e DPDK PMD and behaviour as DPDK Libraries are agnostic to HA or VRRP. Since there is no code snippet shared, I ended up in modifying the `examples/skeleton` to disable promisc mode, but enable multicast via `rte_eth_allmulticast_enable` before `rte_eth_dev_start`. Testing with `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff` and `1:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee` works for me. while `44:44:44:44:44:44` are dropped. If you want I can be available on stackoverflwo chat `dpdk-debug`. https://networklessons.com/multicast/multicast-ip-address-to-mac-address-mapping

Comment: @VipinVarghese we have a date in chat room :) Tnx

Comment: already in chat room and requesting for an update

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT based on chat dpdk-debug] Problem statement is narrowed down to Unable to receive packets with `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF` when promiscuous mode is disabled on X710.

I have disabled `rte_eth_promiscuous_enable` in `DPDK/examples/l2fwd` and `DPDK/examples/skeleton` and testing with PKT-GEN with both `DST-MAC of NIC and FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF` works.

To allow the mutlicast/boradcast frames `x1:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` one needs to enable `rte_eth_allmulticast_enable`

@dimba please feel free test the same, and explore if `rte_eth_dev_mac_addr_add` is causing issues